# Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra flickering screen caused by small drop

Tags: samsung, screen, broken-screen, samsung-galaxy-s-21

About a month ago, I dropped my Samsung Galaxy S21 Ultra about 10 cm above my sink, and it got a small dead pixel on the left edge near the top. The problem is that it has affected the whole area below the impact point, doing so that every time the light intensity gets too bright, for example, if I am accessing a white webpage with light intensity of 100%, the area below the dead pixel just turns black. But if I have the light intensity set to 10%, I can see the screen but the bottom area is still flickering.

I thought I could live with it, but I can't use my phone outside if I can only have the light intensity on 10%.

I know it's something to do with the screen, but I think it's weird that the top works completely fine, and everywhere beneath the impact point is broken. So I hope that it could be a loose cable or something and not the whole screen that has been destroyed due to a small dead pixel.

My question is, do you think it could be a loose cable or another thing I could fix without buying a new screen that costs 270€? Because if that's the case, I think I will just hold on for another month and switch to a new phone.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there may be two connectors to the screen, one for display and the other for touch.  The point of impact has probably damaged the circuit board that the  display is on.  The pixels are laid out in a grid, and a damaged bus means that nothing after that point will work (in that route).

Therefore the screen needs replacing.  Can I suggest that you invest in a decent case for your phone.

Answer (score 0):

It most definitely can be a loose cable. Could also be a busted screen. Only way to know is to check. I myself have repaired tablets and phones that either needed the screen plugged back in or a power connector came loose in a phone, both happened after drops.

Warning, checking yourself will Void your Warranty, but is completely doable. Do so at your own risk.

Will require:

Small Phillips head and Flat head Screwdrivers (Like the size for Glasses).
Some technical knowledge.
Finess

I would look up how to take apart your model as each handset can vary in methods.

If you get the seal apart, be very careful with the screen, one wrong move can destroy it completely.

I recommend taking it to a professional.

But it's definitely doable, and could definitely just have something loose.

Comment: A loose connector does not explain loss of display from impact point.